# Updating checkbox to the server and disable it

Tags: php, ajax, oracle

I have a question regarding my project.
I need to make a database update section which pulls down from the server and showing all the values then update it to the database.

My approach is, getting the value and then display it as a check box. When user select one of the checkboxes, it will change the character from N to Y and then disable it button so people cannot make further update. I can successfully implemented the pulldown and getting the info from the server. but i dont know how to implement the checkbox process, update it to the server and set disable on it.

Please help me

This is the JS section on update_fab.php

```
<script>
// ===================================== //
// ===================================== //
$(function(){
    // SHOW RECORD
    $('#show').click(function () {
        $.post('data2.php', {
            action: "show",
            "hm": $('#headmark').val()
        }, function(res) {
            $('#result').html(res);
        });
    });
});
</script>
<?php
$result = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT HEAD_MARK FROM FABRICATION');
oci_execute($result);

echo '<div class = "wrapper">';
echo '<div id = "contact_form">';
echo '<span>Head mark</span><label><SELECT name="headmark" id="headmark">'.'<br>';
echo '<OPTION VALUE=" ">'."".'</OPTION>';

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_ASSOC)) {
    $HM = $row ['HEAD_MARK'];
    echo "<OPTION VALUE='$HM'>$HM</OPTION>";
}
echo '</SELECT></label><br />';
?>
<input class ="showButton" type="button" value="show" name="SHOW RECORD" id="show"/>
```

and on the data2.php

```
// IF SHOW KEY HAS BEEN PRESSED
if ($_POST['action'] == 'show') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM SUB_MASTER_DRAWING
        WHERE SUB_MASTER_DRAWING.HEAD_MARK = '{$_POST["hm"]}'";
    $query = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
    $query_exec = oci_execute($query);
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo '<div id="content">';
        echo '<table cellspacing = "0"';
        echo '<tr><th>Head Mark</th>
            <th>Cutting</th>
            <th>Assembly</th>
            <th>Welding</th>
            <th>Drilling</th>
            <th>Finishing</th>
            <th>Update</tr>';
        echo "<tr><td><b>$row[HEAD_MARK]/$row[ID]</b></td>                                      
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='check'/></td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='check'/></td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='check'/></td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='check'/></td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='check'/></td>
            <td><input type='button' value='UPDATE' name='updatefab'/></td>
            </tr>";
        if (isset($_POST['updatefab'])) {
            echo '<script type = "text/javascript">submit pressed !</script>';
        }
        echo '<table cellspacing = "0"';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code. We cannot answer your question without knowing what you have done so far.

Comment: my bad, here is my code